# Clear a non-global timeout launched in jQuery plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, settimeout

I try to set a timeout on an element, fired with a jQuery plugin. This timeout is set again in the function depending on conditions. But, I want to clear this element's timeout before set another (if I relaunch the plug-in), or clear this manually.

`<div id="aaa" style="top: 0; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #ff0000;"></div>`

Here's my code (now on http://jsfiddle.net/Ppvf9/)

```
$(function() {

    $('#aaa').myPlugin(0);

});



(function($) {


$.fn.myPlugin = function(loops) {

    loops = loops === undefined ? 0 : loops;

    this.each(function() {

        var el = $(this),
            loop = loops,
            i = 0;

        if (loops === false) {
            clearTimeout(el.timer);
            return;
        }

        var animate = function() {
            var hPos = 0;
            hPos = (i * 10) + 'px';

            el.css('margin-top', hPos);
            if (i < 25) {
                i++;
            } else {
                if (loops === 0) {
                    i = 0;
                } else {
                    loop--;
                    if (loop === 0) {
                        return;
                    } else {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            el.timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
                animate();
            }, 1000/25);

        };

        clearTimeout(el.timer);

        //$('<img/>').load(function() {
            // there's more here but it's not very important
            animate();
        //});

    });
    return this;

};


})(jQuery);
```

If I make `$('#element').myPlugin();`, it's launched. If I make it a second time, there's two timeout on it (see it by doing `$('#aaa').myPlugin(0);`
 in console). And I want to be able to clear this with `$('#element').myPlugin(false);`.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT :
SOLVED by setting two var to access `this` and `$(this)` here : http://jsfiddle.net/Ppvf9/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try saving the timeout handle as a property of the element. Or maintain a static lookup table that maps elements to their timeout handles.

Something like this:

```
el.timer = window.setTimeout(...);
```

I assume you need one timer per element. Not a single timer for all elements.

Comment: You mean… Make the timer var a property of `el`? (How can I?)

Comment: Well, I tried to add `clearTimeout(el.timer);` in the function and in the if === false condition (with `el.timer = window.setTimeout(...);
`), it doesn't work…

Comment: I can try to help you if you publish the code somewhere like jsfiddle

Comment: Ok, jsFiddle's down and the issue doesn't render in any other… I edited my question with a full code example.

Comment: Great ! It was actually really slow. Well, on http://jsfiddle.net/Ppvf9/, the other myPlugin calls make the square jump.

Comment: you set timer property on the jQuery object that corresponds to your element. you need to set it on the element itself. 'this' is the element in your case, so set it on 'this' instead of '$(this)'.

Comment: You mean, like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/Ppvf9/1/ (and thanks for your quic answers, btw!)

Comment: yes, except for when the animate() function is called, 'this' is different, so you will need to store it in a variable, or make sure that 'this' still points to the element by invoking animate.apply() or animate.call().

Comment: I think I've understood but to make it sure: could you edit the jsfiddle with your idea?

Comment: Ok, this http://jsfiddle.net/Ppvf9/2/ solve the problem, according to your $(this) / this point. Thanks !